# Adding backbutton on top of child element of Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, back-button, android-toolbar

I have the following Layout file. How can I add a back button (arrow) on top of (or overlayed on, like a z-index) the Imageview child of Toolbar in my below layout?

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<Toolbar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="#313B45"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

Comment: Do you  want a back button that will take you to the previous activity .

Comment: In the left end of toolbar ?

Comment: I want a backbutton that appears overlayed on the ImageView (which itself is on the top-left of the toolbar). On press, it should exit the application.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set home button of toolbar enable by the following line **getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);** and to override the action on back button you have to override onOptionItemSelected method. look for the given code it will help you... :D

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

To override the OnOptionItemSelected use the following code

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```